# How to show this sequence convereges, and calculate its lim?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $\:x\in \mathbb{R}$.
How to calculate the lim of:$$\lim _{n\to \infty }\frac{\left[1x\right]+\left[2x\right]+\left[3x\right]+...+\left[nx\right]}{n^2}$$
([x] is the floor function of x).

So far i just wanted to get some intiution about that lim. It seems to me that is depend on what $x$ is. Because, if $x$ is between $0$ to $1$, then i get $0$. if $x$=$1$ then i get: $$\lim _{n\to \infty }\frac{\left[1x\right]+\left[2x\right]+\left[3x\right]+...+\left[nx\right]}{n^2}\:=\:\lim \:_{n\to \:\infty \:}\frac{1+2+3+...n}{n^2}\:=\lim \:\:_{n\to \:\:\infty \:\:}\frac{\frac{n\left(1+n\right)}{2}}{n^2}\:=\:\frac{1}{2}$$.
So, my intuition is that $$\lim _{n\to \infty }\frac{\left[1x\right]+\left[2x\right]+\left[3x\right]+...+\left[nx\right]}{n^2} = \frac{x}{2}$$

But, how to prove it? thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Use the inequalities which define the integer part: $y-1<[y]\le y$ for $y=x,\dots,nx$ and "eat" a ... sandwich.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just expanding aly's suggestion, we have that
$$A_n=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left\lfloor j x\right\rfloor $$
is between:
$$ \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{j=1}^{n}(jx-1) = \frac{n+1}{2n}\,x-\frac{1}{n} $$
and:
$$ \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{j=1}^{n}(jx) = \frac{n+1}{2n}\,x$$
hence the limit is $\frac{x}{2}$ (as suspected) by squeezing.